# TexStudio - highlighting matching $?

Tags: texstudio

I see that TexStudio highlights matching {} and () , is it possible also to  somehow highlight a matching $  ?

Clearly TexStudio would have to 'know' whether to look forwards or  backwards for the $ (perhaps by differentiating on whether the count of $ is odd or even), so I am guessing this is harder.

Comment: Try if it can highlight matching `\(`  and `\)`. This is the LaTeX way of using inline math.

Comment: i see - i did not know that - thank you !

Comment: And what about $$...$$? The LaTeX way for that is \[...\].

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a recent version of TeXstudio? It works for me in 2.14.2.

[image]